# Spring boot app stopped working after migration from 2.37 to 2.4.1 version, it is working on windows but not on linux machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, migration

below are the logs :

06-Jan-2021 11:24:57.362 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
11:24:57.872 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data resource from pattern 'file:./config/*/application.properties'
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.LocationResourceLoader.getDirectory(LocationResourceLoader.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.LocationResourceLoader.getResources(LocationResourceLoader.java:102)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolvePattern(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:259)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:245)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:219)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:111)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$resolve$1(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:125)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:106)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:93)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:81)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:230)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:217)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:88)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:80)
at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:203)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:196)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:170)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:148)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5140)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'config' is not a directory
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.LocationResourceLoader.getDirectory(LocationResourceLoader.java:137)

Answer (score 1):

Try to using legacy config processing by setting property:

```
spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true
```

or YAML:

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    use-legacy-processing: true
```

You can read more about that in article: https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4

Comment: I have a single application.properties file but I also get this error.
How can I set the "use-legacy-processing" Property?
It seems that Spring Boot cannot even load my application.properties.

Comment: Did you try to add ```spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true``` in application.properties?

Comment: yes, but it seems that not even the application.properties can be loaded. So it doesn´t really work.